# Android frame animation (how to replay)

Tags: android, animation

I am learning android development and trying to make a simple app. Currently it has just one pic of cat and when someone click on that cat, the picture of cat will animate with frame animation. I managed to do animation for single time but when I again click on that picture it doesn't animate. I tried on emulator(gingerbread) and on real device with jellybean.

I don't want animation loop. I just wanted to make animation whenever user click on that animation.

Here is the code of animation.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" android:id="@+id/anim">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat1" android:duration="100" />
---
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/cat15" android:duration="100" />
```

And here is the source code of activity_main.xml

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
```

And the snippet of MainActivity.java

```
 final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
   iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);

   iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call frameAnimation.stop() before calling start().